# POST action lost when login required

Tags: post

I have a POST action that picks up some user input from a source page and uses it to fill some fields in the destination page. The destination page requires logging in separately.

If you're already logged in to the destination page, the POST action works perfectly. However I just discovered that if the user has to log in, the POST action doesn't survive the login page. The user ends up at the destination page without the forms filled in.

I imagine it's posting to the login page, in other words, instead of the destination page.

You don't see the login page if you're already logged in.

I don't control anything about the destination or login page, so ideas about how to set those up won't help. I'm just wondering if there's anything I can do from the client/source page side to work around this, and somehow retain the post info past the login page.

I had this set up using the GET method earlier, and that worked whether you have to log in at the destination page or not, since in that case it was all just in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can check yourself before sending your POST request if the user is logged or not. If the user is not logged, store the data you want to send (for example in session or local storage if it's not sensitive data), make the user logged in and once it's done, send the POST request with the data you saved.

To do this, you need a way to execute a callback function on the user logging in.